# Entity Framework - Too high level of nesting for select

Tags: mysql, linq, frameworks, entity

Hello stackoverflow i am having trouble with a LINQ query.

```
from ri in App.db.RecipeIngredients  
join i in App.db.Ingredients on ri.IngredientID equals i.ID  
join r in App.db.Recipes on ri.RecipeID equals r.ID  
where recipeIDs.Any(rid => rid == ri.RecipeID)  
group new Result()  
{  
   recipe = ri.Recipe,  
   ingredient = ri.Ingredient,  
   quantity = ri.Quantity  
} by ri.RecipeID
```

This is the code that i have made so far, the recipeIDs is a list of ints. but when the recipeIDs list exceeds 30 ints the program breaks with the error "Too high level of nesting for select", i have been googleing, but at this point i have no idea how to fix it. can some of you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by my self, the fix was in the where, i replaced it with:

```
where recipeIDs.Contains(ri.RecipeID)
```